# Joomla Administration of Modules not possible

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a joomla 2.5 that after a migration happens the following problem:

I can not manage one module. When I try to manage in the backend I look this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pVJM.png

(Is not css problem)

Only happens with zentools module, and the rest of modules and frontend works properly.

Any solution or idea?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possibilities:
1. Turn on PHP error_reporting
2. View contains `die()` or `exit()` before all content is loaded

Comment: thanks but errors are activated and no error throw...

die() or exit() i dont know how to use...u can explain me?

thx

Comment: Search in all module files words like `die` or `exit`

Comment: After migrating Joomla 2.5 to a newer version, the module would not all of a sudden have `die` or `exit` embedded in the code.

Comment: Migration of server, version is the same -> joomla 2.5

Comment: So you can also check has script right CHMOD.  What errors have you activated? Activate `E_ALL`